# Changing internal IP address of wireless adapter?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, networking, wireless, configuration

By default, when creating a wireless access point with NetworkManager, it automatically uses `10.42.0.1/24`. Is there a conf where we can change this manually? I'd like it to be on `172.16.0.1/24`.

Some machine specs:

```
Linux Ubuntu 4.4.0-104-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 12:16:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

EDIT:

Using NetworkManger, I set the Wi-Fi Mode to "Hotspot":

[image]
Which automatically sets the IPv4 Method to "Shared to other computers":

[image]

Doing this automatically sets the wlp1s0 interface and default route to 10.42.0.1 --which is manageable, but I would prefer it on 172.16.0.1.

Below is the HOTSPOT conf. I made note of which lines I redacted, it's otherwise exactly the same.

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HOTSPOT

[connection]
id=HOTSPOT
uuid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (redacted)
type=wifi
interface-name=wlp1s0
permissions=user:username:; (redacted)
secondaries=
timestamp=1513484498

[wifi]
band=bg
mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (redacted)
mac-address-blacklist=
mac-address-randomization=0
mode=ap
seen-bssids=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX; (redacted)
ssid=HOTSPOT

[wifi-security]
group=
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=
proto=
psk=password-here (redacted)

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=ignore
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I updated my question. Please let me know if further clarification is needed. I'd really like to figure this out.

Comment: @dessert And I couldn't post the images properly, 10 Reputation points are required, sorry about that.

Comment: @9UR4 what you did was fine - links are OK, we usually go around and us high-rep users can edit them in.  like I just did.  (Comments pruning shall  begin in the next couple hours if I don't forget)

Answer (score 0):

In the section `[ipv4]` of your `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HOTSPOT` file, you can manually include your choice of address as long as you change your `method` of address choice:

```
[ipv4]
method=manual
address1=172.16.0.1/24
```

See `man nm-settings` for (a lot!) more details.